# Python, loops - code results do not match expected outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program for basic addition(+) on mathematics. My code is as follows:

```
   import random

   Totalrounds = input("Input how many rounds you want try? ")

   answerlist = list()


   for i in range(0, int(Totalrounds)):
        numb1 = random.randint(0,9)
        numb2 = random.randint(0,9)            
        print(numb1, "+" , numb2,)
        Answer = int(input("Your answer is? " ))

        if Answer == numb1 + numb2 :
              print("Your answer is correct")
              print()
        else:
              print("Your answer is wrong")
              print("the right answer is ", numb1 + numb2)
              print()  

        answerlist.append(Answer)

   #Result

   print("this is your Answersheet from" ,Totalrounds, "question")

   for i in range(0, len(answerlist)):
      if answerlist[i] == numb1 + numb2 :
         Result1 = "correct"
         print (numb1, "+" , numb2, "=" ,answerlist[i], Result1 ,)
      else:
         Result1 = "wrong"
         print (numb1, "+" , numb2, "=" ,answerlist[i], Result1 ,)
```

If I put totalrounds around 5, on #result print, the question 1 - 4 will have different number from upper list. can anyone tell me what I did wrong in this code and what can i do to make it same like upper list question ? 
question = numb1 "+" numb2

thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that are problematic or style related in your code.

In the second `for` loop you try to access the `numb1`/`numb2` but they are not relevant because each iteration of the first `for` loop you change them so to overcome this issue you need to store them as well.

There is no need to set `range` to start from 0, this is the default value.

When initiating a `list` there is no need to do `list()` just `[]` is enough.

a correction to your code is as follows:

```
import random

Totalrounds = input("Input how many rounds you want try? ")

answerlist = []
numb1_list = []
numb2_list = []


for i in range(int(Totalrounds)):
    numb1 = random.randint(0,9)
    numb1_list.append(numb1)
    numb2 = random.randint(0,9)
    numb2_list.append(numb2)
    print(numb1, "+" , numb2,)
    Answer = int(input("Your answer is? " ))
    if Answer == numb1 + numb2 :
          print("Your answer is correct")
          print()
    else:
          print("Your answer is wrong")
          print("the right answer is ", numb1 + numb2)
          print()

    answerlist.append(Answer)

#Result

print("this is your Answersheet from" ,Totalrounds, "question")

for i in range(len(answerlist)):
  if answerlist[i] == numb1_list[i] + numb2_list[i] :
     Result1 = "correct"
     print (numb1_list[i], "+" , numb2_list[i], "=" ,answerlist[i], Result1 ,)
  else:
     Result1 = "wrong"
     print (numb1_list[i], "+" , numb2_list[i], "=" ,answerlist[i], Result1 ,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You store the values of the answers in `answerlist` but you only store the most recent values of `numb1` and `numb2` so they are always printed as the same.

If you want to print all the previous questions you should store them in a list too.

Then change the print statement at the end

`print (numb1list[i], "+" , numb2list[i], "=" ,answerlist[i], Result1)`

Comment: ah i see, i need to store the numb1 and numb2 too, as a list . 
thanks you so much for your help